# Find nested object based on a parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array which looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "boxes": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "content": {
          "name": "ABC",
          "details": "some details for abc"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "boxes": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "content": {
          "name": "XYZ",
          "details": "some details for xyz"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "content": {
          "name": "UVW",
          "details": "some details for uvw"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {}
]
```

And I have a variable: `let id = 3`

I want to be able to search through the nested array `"boxes"` to find the `content` property of the object that have the given id. Such that the result is:

```
{
   "name": "XYZ",
   "details": "some details for xyz"
}
```

Till now I have gathered that I can use a combination forEach and .filter do find this. But I'm not sure how. Also, I have control over the original data. So, if there's a better way to store the original data, I will be glad to have suggestions.

Actually I did attempt but got stuck:

Let's say the original array is called house.

```
let matches = []
let id = 3
house.forEach(function(e) {
 matches = matches.concat(e.boxes.filter(function(b) {
                return (b.id === id);
            }));})
console.log(matches[0].content)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `map` method by passing a *callback* function as argument. The scope of `map` method is to get all items from `boxes` array.

Also, I'm using `filter(Boolean)` statement in order to remove `undefined` value for those items which doesn't have `boxes` as property.

At least, use `find` method in order to get the desired output result.

```js
let arr = [ { "boxes": [ { "id": 2, "content": { "name": "ABC", "details": "some details for abc" } } ] }, { "boxes": [ { "id": 3, "content": { "name": "XYZ", "details": "some details for xyz" } }, { "id": 4, "content": { "name": "UVW", "details": "some details for uvw" } } ] }, {} ]
let id = 1;
let result = [].concat(...arr.map(item => item.boxes))
            .filter(Boolean)
            .find(({id}) => id == id).content;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. Can you explain what the Boolean is for?

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to put boxes object into one array, it seems it just has couple extra levels you don't need; You can create a helper function for that.
2. make a loop with if statement if there is what you are looking for or not

Answer (score 0):

Here I use `forEach()` to loop through the data and get the boxes.

After that, I use `filter()` to get the object with the desired id. That's all.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "boxes": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "content": {
          "name": "ABC",
          "details": "some details for abc"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "boxes": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "content": {
          "name": "XYZ",
          "details": "some details for xyz"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "content": {
          "name": "UVW",
          "details": "some details for uvw"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {}
]


data.forEach(data => {
  if (data.boxes){
    let searchedData = data.boxes.filter(box => box.id == 3);
    if (searchedData.length > 0){
      console.log(searchedData[0].content);
    }
  }
});
```